# Is it ok to attempt to write in french?

Tags: discussion, language

Is it ok to attempt to write in French my question, even though it probably contains some errors, and then hope a reviewer corrects them? In this way we could learn a lot more, by learning from our mistakes and by improving our French writing skills...

Comment: Check maybe http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/547/ or http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/445/ and included links.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, it's even [encouraged](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to write your question in French, as long as you can make yourself understood. People here expect that your French may not be perfect and will usually edit your question if they spot mistakes.

The one thing that could make you hesitate is that if you ask in French, people will usually answer in French. If you don't feel capable of understanding answers in French, it would be best to ask in English. But of course if someone answers in French and you have trouble understanding the answer, you're welcome to request clarifications.

Comment: Time to use my limited french: Merci Gilles pour ta réponse. 
(I bet I did a mistake there, lol)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. No you didn't!

Comment: @An old man in the sea And you did not fall into the standard "merci de"/"merci pour" trap.